# Access based on Record Type

Tags: profile, account, record-type

I have 2 record types for accounts - RT1 and RT2. And I have one profile - Sales Reps

This profile should have Read/Write access on RT1 and only Read Access on RT2.

Accounts OWD is Private.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: It's private. I updated the question

Comment: I would consider using page layouts to set fields to read only and a validation rule to enforce locking as page layouts don't prevent edits by api, etc.  This would be pretty simple to implement.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do a sharing based on Profile out of box.You will need a role or a public group .

You will need to use criteria based sharing rule to achieve this .[image]

Update

Looks like the sharing is not just based on record type. In this case this will be an after insert and after update to further customize logic and add account sharing records.

Comment: How will sharing rule help here? For the same profile I need different type of access based on the record type

Comment: Based on record type you will decide the access .You will need two rules for two different types with write and read only access .Only thing is you need a public group

Comment: Agree that it will restrict the access but Adding sharing rule will also the expand the universe of accounts visible to sales reps. So every sales rep will start seeing all the accounts with RT1 and RT2.

Comment: When you create sharing rule you specify public group .So you will add only users that need access to the public group .

Comment: This needs to happen for every user in the profile

Comment: Yes so add all users of that profile to the group  What's your issue here ?

Comment: Each Sales Reps have their accounts aligned via AccountShare. They don't see every account in the universe. So if I am a sales rep, I have only 100 accounts aligned to me in AccountShare. Out of these 100, I should be able to Read/Write RT1s and Read RT2s.  If we create the sharing rule (as you explained), I'll start seeing more than 100 records which should not happen.

Comment: I see now what you need. You will end up writing a trigger after insert and after update of account to further share via apex sharing

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/48057/discussion-between-mohith-shrivastava-and-maneesh-gupta).